# Django Model's DateTimeField is taking UTC even when timezone is Asia/Calcutta everywhere

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime, timezone

I am using `Django 1.11`. 
My `settings.py` has following configured:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

which is IST (Indian Standard Time). My system is set to IST. `MySQL` `current_time` returns IST, Django's server when running, shows timestamp in IST. Python's `datetime.now()` also gives IST.

Now the problem is, my `models.py` has following fields:

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and the database is MySQL. When I insert any record in it, the timestamps are in **UTC**. I was thinking of adding some middleware, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132924/5130528) answer, but that doesn't feel to be the recommended way. Why is it taking UTC even when everywhere IST has been configured? Am I missing some config that needs to be set separately for models?

**Please note** that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47132548/5130528) is not similar to what I require. I want to change the overall timezone, so that it is effective in model's too.

Comment: try USE_TZ = True

Comment: check this https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/07/django-with-time-zone-support-and-mysql/

Comment: I've already set `USE_TZ = True`.  This https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/07/django-with-time-zone-support-and-mysql/ does work, but it is again sort of a middleware. I am interested in knowing that from where is Model still taking UTC, when I've set IST everywhere, and I want to update that exact point, instead of using any middleware each time.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks, that's what I was looking for.
So, if I change it to `False`, will it work fine? After changing it to  `False` , will it take System's timezone or the timezone specified in settings ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`datetimes` will [always be stored in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33281514/2395796) if `USE_TZ` is `True`.

The only way around that is to set `USE_TZ` to `False`. `auto_now` [uses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) `django.utils.timezone.now()`, which [is defined to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) the following:

> If `USE_TZ` is `False`, this will be a naive datetime (i.e. a datetime without an associated timezone) that represents the current time in the system’s local timezone.

Which sounds like what you're asking for.

But are you sure that's what you want? Since `Asia/Calcutta` [had DST in the past](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata?syear=1925) there will be times that you simply can't represent unambiguously in the database. That's why UTC is the standard choice for storing datetimes.