# Django - How can I set manually DateTimeField value given date and time?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

How can I set manually DateTimeField value given date and time ?

Here is my model and I am trying to assign date & time value to "created_at" field:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
​
    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee.username
​
```

Here is something I tried in the console:​
​

```
> o = Attendance.objects.last()
> o.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 26, 0, 45, 31, 829827, tzinfo=<UTC>)
> x = datetime.strptime('17/07/2018 12:20', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
> x
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 12, 20)
>o.updated_at = x
o.save()
>z = Attendance.objects.last()
>z.updated_at
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

notice that I set "2018, 7, 17" but it appears "2018, 7, 29". is the assignment correct ? probably it needs the timezone as well.

Comment: Are you sure o and z are the same object?  This code seems correct, but it may be that changing / saving the objects makes a different object respond to the 'Attendance.objects.last()'.

Comment: yes its same, in development on my local machine. i was told that auto_now_add could be a problem, should use default instead

Comment: You realize that your auto_now might be working and overriding your updated_at field, right?  Since you're updating the updated_at field and getting a result of today, it seems that you're getting one of two possibly correct results depending on when the auto_now is applied.

Comment: oh didnt realize that, was testing on updated_at instead since i didnt want to touch created_at

Comment: Perhaps you could add an extra field to check the updated_at.....  To me it looks like your code is working as written.

Comment: "Attendance.created_at received a naive datetime (2018-07-17 12:20:00) while time zone support is active."   i seem to get this now, since removing the auto_now_add, how should i put in the time zone from x = datetime.strptime('17/07/2018 12:20', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

Comment: my timezone is 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones gives some info.  Basically you need to add an offset to the time zone.

Comment: instead of EST i tried putting Asia/Kuala_Lumpur for the timezone, doesnt seem to have an effect

Answer (score 1):

`datetimes` will [always be stored in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33281514/2395796) if `USE_TZ` is `True`.

The only way around that is to set `USE_TZ` to `False`. `auto_now` [uses `django.utils.timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add), which [is defined to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) the following:

> If `USE_TZ` is `False`, this will be a naive datetime (i.e. a datetime without an associated timezone) that represents the current time in the system’s local timezone.

Converting time and storing it in DB is not a good method, So, convert the time whenever you need

Answer (score 0):

So, if what you're trying to do is set the updated_at field to the current Asia/Kuala_Lumpur timezone, you want to generate the datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, tzinfo=) with an appropriate tzinfo value.

This is a combination of the following two Stack Overflow answers:

[Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

[Is there a list of Pytz Timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866926/is-there-a-list-of-pytz-timezones)

Your resulting call will reference

```
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
```

And the call will probably look like:

```
x = datetime.tzinfo("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")
y = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 29, 12, 0, 13, 204815, x)
```

Comment: it doesnt work. it has this error TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'. perhaps it should work something like this ? not sure. i event tried your code with "US/Pacific"

Comment: Worked with it a little in the console and I think that solves your issue.